# what is the meaning of "no problem" in British English?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is the scenario:

Today I asked my teacher whether I will get late penalty due to some reasons.

The teacher says "no problem."

Can I consider the response of "no problem" as I will not get penalty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means your circumstances present no problem for the teacher and you will not be penalized due to your situation.

Comment: I'd say that's conjecture at best.  It really isn't  clear what the teacher meant.

Comment: @AlexWei, while we here at ELU can comment only on the words as written, the way your teacher said it would have contained some kind of clue on intention. If she spoke cheerfully, then you probably have nothing to worry about. If she sounded sarcastic, well, that's a different story. Oftentimes, it's not just about the phrasing.

Comment: I have been unable to find an alternate definition for ["no problem."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_problem)  Not sure where the disagreement is coming from here.

Comment: @migs Today I asked some of my foreign friends whose first language is English. They are not sure about it and asked me to talk to the teacher again. I explained I am not very sure about whether I will get late penalty to the teacher again. The teacher said no problem again twice. When I learnt English, usually "no problem" means Ok ,yes, you're welcome...  I can only assume it means I won't get penalty. But thanks for your help